# How to move paging dropdown to bottom beside showing number of jQuery Ajax DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

Here I have one issue relevant to dropdown of jQuery Ajax DataTable. I want to move paging dropdown to bottom.

I have lost of r&d on same but Can't found anything.

Please have a look following image which I want exact.

[image]

Can Anyone help me for the same.

Comment: please share code so we can see what you did so far

Comment: it's a simple code for initialize datatable as follow `$ ('#datatable').DataTable ({
                        "order": [[1, "desc"]],
                        "sDom": 'rtlfip',...`

Comment: then my friend @HiteshTank it's simple if you did google https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html

Comment: yes I have found. I have made for the same

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to config the layout of `DataTables` by setting `dom` option, the documentation is [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom).

By default, the `dom` looks like this:

```
{
    dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>>" +
         "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
         "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
}
```

We can change it to:

```
{
    dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-6 col-offset-sm-6'f>>" +
         "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
         "<'row'<'col-sm-3'i><'col-sm-2'l><'col-sm-7'p>>",
}
```

Which use the Bootstrap grid system. For other layout system like `Foundation` and `jQueryUI`, checkout the documentation.